# Error after upgrading to iOS 7.1 SDK - implicit conversions with precision loss no longer allowed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just upgraded Xcode + iOS SDK to the latest versions (5.1/7.1) and am now getting a bunch of errors about implicit conversions losing precision (`NSInteger` to `int` etc).

Does anybody know if there is a compiler flag or something that allows me to tell the compiler to treat those as warnings rather than errors again? I couldn't find anything so far. I really don't want to go through the code and add explicit casts everywhere as this would be in a lot of places.

Comment: They are errors for a reason. You should probably take this opportunity to improve your codebase

Answer (score 3):

This is an error for good reason. NSInteger throughout your codebase will make sure that when you compile the code for 32 and 64 bit iOS devices they are handled consistently. In the 32 bit world NSInteger and int were the same, but with the advent of the iPhone 5S and the iPad Air, iOS is no longer 32 bit only.

As others have said, there really is no way around this if you don't want trouble with modern devices.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get back to work and deal with this problem later, then you need to remove `arm64` from the 'Valid Architectures' and 'Architectures' items in your project's Build Settings.

As others have said, you really should fix the warnings, but this was a nasty little surprise by Apple (that is, adding the arm64 architecture to Build Settings on Xcode 5.1) so I can totally understand wanting to put these warnings away for a while and work on what ever you were working on before you decided to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! A bunch of the code that was failing are external plugins, so I'd rather wait for them to be fixed than doing it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed XCode now includes the arm64 architecture. 
NSInteger is something completely different now as it is define in NSObjCRuntime.h :

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

To deal with it you should improve your codebase. First of all, you have to be really consistent. Assign NSInteger only to NSInteger and not to int. Avoid all kind of :

> int i = [aString integerValue] ( as it returns a NSInteger)

but

> NSInteger i = [aString integerValue] (and if it's a long type then you won't have any trouble.)

Moreover, another issue you might have is when you want to create a string from a value.
What you could do is something like:

```
#define cL(v)    (long)(v)
#define cUL(v)   (unsigned long)(v)

NSLog(@"array.count: %ld", cUL(anArray.count));
```

array.count returns an unsigned int under armv7(s) and an unsigned long under arm64. By always casting into an unsigned long you will not face any warning anymore and, more important, do not get any bug.

This "logic" have been introduced by Apple itself on some tech-talks videos there:
https://developer.apple.com/tech-talks/videos/ (video "Architecting Modern iOS Games". Play the video around 10m00s)

Answer (score 0):

You should go and cast them the way they ought to be. Apple isn't complaining for no reason - it also ensures that you don't get any weird unexpected behaviour later down the line. I suggest you go and cast them all. It's extreme but well, it's clean.

Comment: Not as clean as using `NSInteger` instead of `int`.

Comment: I agree with @kevin here.  Use `NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` in the appropriate places and use `int` and `unsigned int` in the appropriate places.  I've seen code that uses `int` when `NSInteger` is called for and `NSInteger` when `int` is called for.  Both will generate warnings.