# Failure when building for ios 64bit

Tags: ios, xcode, 64-bit

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jamesrosso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/News_Center-asepzfqbmsxlpldctqvpsukwipxp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/jamesrosso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/News_Center-asepzfqbmsxlpldctqvpsukwipxp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CDVLocalNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification:] in AppDelegate.o
  "_CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:handleOpenURL:] in AppDelegate.o
      -[CDVInAppBrowser openInSystem:] in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVInAppBrowser in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVUserAgentUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVWebViewDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandDelegateImpl", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandDelegate in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVCommandQueue", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainCommandQueue in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVInAppBrowser in CDVInAppBrowser.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MainViewController in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to remove arm64 from the 'Valid Architectures' and 'Architectures' items in your project's Build Settings, see [Error after upgrading to iOS 7.1 SDK - implicit conversions with precision loss no longer allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313499/error-after-upgrading-to-ios-7-1-sdk-implicit-conversions-with-precision-loss)